# Transforming (removing and renaming) xml file tags using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have just started learning xslt and I am very new to this. Which is why I am here to ask this after retrying it multiple times and not getting the desired output. I have this input xml :

```
<root>
<type>sometype</type>
<attribute name="1st" value="val1"/>
<attribute name="2nd" value="val2"/>
<attribute name="nth" value="valn"/>
  <attribute name="first">
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue1">
        <new>
          <type>TypeA</type>
          <attribute name="attr1" value="aaa" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
  </attribute>
  <attribute name="second">
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue2">
        <new>
          <type>TypeB</type>
          <attribute name="attr2" value="bbb" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
  </attribute>
  <attribute name="third">
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue3">
        <new>
          <type>TypeC</type>
          <attribute name="attr3" value="ccc" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
  </attribute>
</root>
```

which needs to be transformed to this output xml :

```
<root>
<type>sometype</type>
<attribute name="1st" value="val1"/>
<attribute name="2nd" value="val2"/>
<attribute name="nth" value="valn"/>
  <attribute name="common">
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue1">
        <new>
          <type>TypeA</type>
          <attribute name="attr1" value="aaa" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue2">
        <new>
          <type>TypeB</type>
          <attribute name="attr2" value="bbb" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
    <tagvalue>
      <entryMap name="mapvalue3">
        <new>
          <type>TypeC</type>
          <attribute name="attr3" value="ccc" />
        </new>
      </entryMap>
    </tagvalue>
  </attribute>
</root>
```

That is, there are 3 occurrences of this tag : `<attribute name="first">` `<attribute name="second">` `<attribute name="third">`. I need to have just one occurrence of this at the beginning and rename the name value to "common" i.e. `<attribute name="common">`.
I tried using `<xsl:template match="@value">`for the renaming logic but I am not able to successfully incorporate it.

The current xslt I have is this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="removeElementsNamed" select="'attribute'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:if test="not(name() = $removeElementsNamed)">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I know I am doing it wrong somewhere. I tried using multiple templates but I am not getting the desired output. I would be very thankful if someone could help me out with this. Thank you!

Comment: You've given an example, but you haven't tried to tell us what the general rules are; there's therefore a danger that any solution provided here works on your example, but doesn't work on real-life data. (One example doesn't constitute a specification). In particular, I'm left wondering what's special about the last three `attribute` elements that means these should be grouped and others shouldn't. Is it their names? or their position? or the fact that they have child elements? And how might the real-life input vary from your sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <attribute name="common">
            <xsl:copy-of select="attribute/tagvalue"/>
        </attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To copy the other elements that are not included in the "common" group, you could do:

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="type | attribute[not(@name='first' or @name='second' or @name='third')]"/>
            <attribute name="common">
                <xsl:copy-of select="attribute[@name='first' or @name='second' or @name='third']/tagvalue"/>
            </attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Or, a little more elegantly (to avoid testing the same thing twice):

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="common" select="attribute[@name='first' or @name='second' or @name='third']" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[count(.|$common) != count($common)]"/>
        <attribute name="common">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$common/tagvalue"/>
        </attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This did solve the issue I was facing. But if in my input xml I have attribute tags after root like :
`<root>
<type>type1</type>
<attribute name="a"/>
<attribute name="b"/>
...
<attribute name="n"/>
  <attribute name="first">
    <tagvalue>`
then this xslt removes all those attribute and type tags after root. I need to keep them. Could you please advise how can I achieve that?

Comment: Please edit your question and add an anxample of such input and the expected result of transforming it. --- P.S. Your terminology is confusing: there are no "tags" in XSLT; the process operates on a tree of *nodes*, mostly *elements* and *attributes*. And the author of your XML is adding to the confusion by giving an element the name "attribute".

Comment: I have edited the input xml file and the desired output xml file as mentioned. Please kindly help me with this. Also, I apologize for my terminologies. I am very new to this and still trying to grasp the nomenclature and terminologies of it. Trying to learn new concepts on it daily. Thank you for your advice, will definitely keep it in mind going forward!!

Comment: See the addition to my answer. -- BTW, which XSLT processor will you be using? Some processors support the `set:difference` extension function, which is more elegant than the native expression I have used.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Currently I am using an online tool for the transformation : [https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output]. Will surely go through the `set:difference` function. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't know why you would choose an online tool, but in any case that site uses a processor that supports XSLT 3.0. In XSLT 2.0 or higher you can use the `except` operator e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="* except $common"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way this could be done :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="attribute[1]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">common</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//attribute/tagvalue"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="attribute[position()>1]"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's one way this could be done : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVbv/2