# Renaming xml attribute value if another attribute has a specific value using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to transform my input xml to output xml using XSLT based on certain conditions.

My input xml :

```
<top>
<type>Random value</type>
<attribute name="a"/>
<attribute name="b"/>
...
<attribute name="n"/>
  <attribute name="some value">
    <mapResponses>
      <entryMap name="value1">
        <section>
          <type>STATUS_RESPONSE</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Row Line" />
          <attribute name="abc" value="def" />
          ...
          <attribute name="hju" value="tyu" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value2">
        <section>
          <type>STATUS_RESPONSE</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Column value" />
          <attribute name="mno" value="pqr" />
          ...
          <attribute name="olp" value="tre" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value3">
        <section>
          <type>STATUS_RESPONSE</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Other random value" />
          <attribute name="oui" value="fry" />
          ...
          <attribute name="tgy" value="adr" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value4">
        <section>
         .....
        </section>
      </entryMap>
       <entryMap name="...">
        <section>
         .....
        </section>
      </entryMap>
    </mapResponses>
  </attribute>
</top>
```

to be transformed to this output xml :

```
<top>
<type>Random value</type>
<attribute name="a"/>
<attribute name="b"/>
...
<attribute name="n"/>
  <attribute name="some value">
    <mapResponses>
      <entryMap name="value1">
        <section>
          <type>CREATE_ROW</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Row Line" />
          <attribute name="abc" value="def" />
          ...
          <attribute name="hju" value="tyu" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value2">
        <section>
          <type>CREATE_COLUMN</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Column value" />
          <attribute name="mno" value="pqr" />
          ...
          <attribute name="olp" value="tre" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value3">
        <section>
          <type>CREATE_COLUMN</type>
          <attribute name="status_code" value="1001" />
          <attribute name="status_detail" value="OK" />
          <attribute name="type" value="Other random value" />
          <attribute name="oui" value="fry" />
          ...
          <attribute name="tgy" value="adr" />
        </section>
      </entryMap>
      <entryMap name="value4">
        <section>
         .....
        </section>
      </entryMap>
       <entryMap name="...">
        <section>
         .....
        </section>
      </entryMap>
    </mapResponses>
  </attribute>
</top>
```

So, when I have `<attribute name="type" value="Row Line" />` the `<type>STATUS_RESPONSE</type>` needs to be changed to `<type>CREATE_ROW</type>`. And when I have `<attribute name="type" value="Column value" />` or `<attribute name="type" value="Other random value" />` or any `<attribute name="type" value="..." />` where value is NOT Row Line, the `<type>STATUS_RESPONSE</type>` needs to be changed to `<type>CREATE_COLUMN</type>`.
The ... are mentioned to generalize the xml that it can contain more content but in same levels.
The `<attribute name="type" value="..." />` is always at the 3rd position after STATUS_RESPONSE as mentioned in the input and output xml.

The current XSLT I have is this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="type">
      <xsl:for-each select="attribute[@name='type'][@value='Row Line']">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:value-of select="CREATE_ROW"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  
    <xsl:template match="type">
      <xsl:for-each select="attribute[@name='type'][@value!='Row Line']">
        <xsl:copy/>
        <xsl:value-of select="CREATE_COLUMN"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not able to get my desired output from this XSLT. I am very new to XSLT and I just started working on it. Please kindly help me out with this. Thank You!

Comment: Is this some kind of homework? You are the third person that has "just started to learn XSLT" and has a question based on what seems a very similar input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729181/creating-new-attribute-based-on-another-attribute-value-in-xml-using-xslt and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71653306/transforming-removing-and-renaming-xml-file-tags-using-xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two templates both matching `type` (so last one in the stylesheet would "win"), then you had a for loop that was looking for `attribute` elements that were children of `type` (there are none, because they are siblings).

Move the criteria matching the `type` elements into a predicate, looking for the `attribute` elements on the `following-sibling::` axis, and in the second template, no need to assert that the `@value` is not equal to `'Row Line'` since the other one already matches when it does (and avoids any potential issues with `!=` on sets where most people really mean `not(@value='Row Line')`).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="type[following-sibling::attribute[@name='type' and @value='Row Line']]">
        <xsl:copy>CREATE_ROW</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="type[following-sibling::attribute[@name='type']]">
        <xsl:copy>CREATE_COLUMN</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```